# How can i specify a Http Method for a specific route in express-unless?

Tags: express, express-jwt

i'm using express-jwt to restrict access to my API routes.

```js
app.use(expressJWT(
    { secret: process.env.JWT_PASSPHRASE })
    .unless({
        path: [
            '/login',
            '/users',
            { url: '/', methods: ['POST'] }]
    })
)
```

now the /login route is accessible without token as expected.

Now I would like to allow the /users routes too with but with POST method only ,

I've trying this according to the documentation but i'm pretty sure i'm doing it wrong because all the request methods targetting /users are open.

Second options that I've tested:

```js
app.use(expressJWT(
    { secret: process.env.JWT_PASSPHRASE })
    .unless({
        path: [
            '/login',
            '/users',
            { url: '/users', methods: ['POST'] }]
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some research i've made a custom callback as follows:

```js
app.use(expressJWT(
    { secret: process.env.JWT_PASSPHRASE })
    .unless( req =>{
        return(
            req.originalUrl === '/login' ||
            req.originalUrl === '/users' && req.method === 'POST'
        )

    })
)
```